# filter by Date in sql statement not working

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, date

i cannot filter by date  i am using visual studio 2010 and C# 
here are the simplified statement i try with no success

```
SELECT     date_dt, ident_1, ident_2, ident_3
FROM         p240538
WHERE     (date_dt >= DateTime('"2011' / 10 / '19"'))
```

or

```
SELECT     date_dt, ident_1, ident_2, ident_3
FROM         p240538
WHERE     (date_dt >= "2011/10/19"))
```

any ideas??

thanks

Comment: Are you getting zero results or an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were close.  Looks like you want something like:

```
SELECT     date_dt, ident_1, ident_2, ident_3
FROM         p240538
WHERE     (date_dt >= DateTime(2011, 10, 19))
```

EDIT:
First thought this was a linq question, and after submitting it realized it was a sql question.  Try:

```
SELECT     date_dt, ident_1, ident_2, ident_3
FROM         p240538
WHERE     (date_dt >= convert(DateTime, '10/19/2011', 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     date_dt, ident_1, ident_2, ident_3 
FROM         p240538 
WHERE     datediff(dd, date_dt, getdate()) <= @theMaxNumberOfDayDifference
```

What you're looking for is the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function in SQL Server.  What it does is compare dates.  I used a variable to compare it to, but you can have a hard-coded value there if you like.  What it does is compare your `date_dt` field to the current date.  If the number of days (you can change `dd` to any other scope of comparison as specified in my link) is less than or equal to today's date then it'll return those records.

EDIT: this is assuming that `date_dt` field is of `datetime` or equivalent datatype.  You can also substitute `getdate()` with any valid `datetime` specification, including a string of the datetime you are looking to compare against.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
SELECT    date_dt, ident_1, ident_2, ident_3
FROM      p240538
WHERE     CONVERT(VARCHAR, date_dt, 112) >= 20111019
```

Of course, it would help us better if you could provide the data structure/type/setting of the `date_dt` column (since my suggestion could drastically change should `date_dt` be an index, and what kind of date do you need to provide (if it's always in the `yyyy/mm/dd` format). Is the date also a parameter?

Comment: @BayoAlen ok, then check out my answer.  That should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

`SELECT date_dt, ident_1, ident_2, ident_3 
FROM   p240538 
WHERE  date_dt >= '10/19/2011'`
The code is SQL and has nothing to do with Visual Studio or C#

Comment: The main reason for actually doing the conversion yourself is that you know the format of the constant and SQL Server can easily get the month and day parts confused if you don't tell it.  In most cases, your answer will work, but not all.